# 4 pair of cables lead to Ceiling fan box

Tags: ceiling-fan

I've got two power switches that go to this ceiling fan. Both switches would cut power to the fan and to the light.

It's been so long since I took it down I don't remember how it goes. I've got 4 pairs of cables leading into the box. 1 hot, 3 hot/1 neutral together, and 3 neutral together.

I read this: [Why are there four electrical lines (12 wires) in this ceiling fan box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66927/why-are-there-four-electrical-lines-12-wires-in-this-ceiling-fan-box)

But I don't understand if I use the standalone black cable for power and just tie in my fan's neutral to the 3 neutral cable or just tie into the black and neutral bundle.

[image]

Comment: White isn't neutral.  It's either neutral or hot.  In the case of 3 blacks and a white, it is not neutral.   A more competent electrician would have put black tape on the wire to indicate that.  That linked article is actually backwards, the marked white should be with the always-hots, the solitary black should be switched hot.  Yours is wired correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have a switch loop here

The white wire bundled in with the blacks along with the solo black wire are telltale signs of an old-style *switch loop* run using /2 cable from the fixture to the switch(es), with the white wire as the always hot and the black as the switched hot in your case. So, with the power off at the breaker:

- Use a wrap of black electrical tape to mark the white wire nutted in with the blacks as a hot wire
- Nut the ceiling fan black and blue (or just the black, if you don't have a light kit on your fan) wires to the lone black wire
- Nut the ceiling fan white wire to the existing bundle of entirely white wires
- And nut the ceiling fan green wire to the existing bundle of bare wires.

Comment: this worked, I tried to give you points, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

### The two switches are a red herring

The loose black wire, and the "outlier" white wire (white amongst blacks) go into the same cable and comprise a *switch loop*, as ThreePhaseEel discusses.

However, instead of going to a single switch (as is the case with most switch loop illustrations you will find), they actually go into a "3-way switch complex".  Because of the wiring topology (all the 3-ways off on a branch of their own), they *emulate* a plain switch, and can be thought of as a plain switch from the fan's perspective.  So in this case, you can ignore the fact that there is a 3-way complex involved.